# How to get data(s) from a dropdown on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get all the options of a dropdown transposed in a row, but I could not find a way to do it.

Let's say the dropdown has simple options
1
2
3
4

I need to extract all values to a row. Can be transposed to row, to a single cell, concatenated, doesn't matter. I just need to extract those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of the dropdown list in a cell, and put the values to the row direction.

In this answer, I would like to propose a custom function using Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the container-bound script of Google Spreadsheet. And please put `=SAMPLE("A1")` to a cell. By this, the script is run as the custom function. And the values of dropdown list are put to the row.

```
/**
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function SAMPLE(input) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = input.indexOf('!') > 0 ? ss.getSheetByName(input.substring(0, input.indexOf('!'))) : ss.getActiveSheet();
  const range = input.indexOf('!') > 0 ? input.substring(input.indexOf('!') + 1, input.length) : input;
  const dataValudations = sheet.getRange(range).getDataValidations();
  return dataValudations.reduce((ar, r) => {
    r.forEach(c => {
      if (c) {
        const temp = c.getCriteriaValues()[0];
        if (c.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_LIST) {
          ar = ar.concat(temp.map(e => [e]));
        } else if (c.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE) {
          ar = ar.concat(temp.getValues().flat().map(e => [e]));
        } else {
          ar.push([""]);
        }
      } else {
        ar.push([""]);
      }
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
}
```

#### Result:

When the cell "A1" has the dropdown list which has the values of `1,2,3,4`, the above script returns the following result.

[image]

- If you want to put the values to the column direction, please use the following script.

  ```
   /**
    * @OnlyCurrentDoc
    */
    function DROPDOWN_VALUES(input) {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const sheet = input.indexOf('!') > 0 ? ss.getSheetByName(input.substring(0, input.indexOf('!'))) : ss.getActiveSheet();
      const range = input.indexOf('!') > 0 ? input.substring(input.indexOf('!') + 1, input.length) : input;
      const dataValudations = sheet.getRange(range).getDataValidations();
      return dataValudations.reduce((ar, r) => {
        r.forEach(c => {
          if (c) {
            const temp = c.getCriteriaValues()[0];
            if (c.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_LIST) {
              // ar = ar.concat(temp.map(e => [e]));
              ar.push(temp);
            } else if (c.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE) {
              // ar = ar.concat(temp.getValues().flat().map(e => [e]));
              ar.push(temp.getValues().flat());
            } else {
              ar.push([""]);
            }
          } else {
            ar.push([""]);
          }
        });
        return ar;
      }, []);
    }
  ```

  - Result

    [image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [getDataValidations()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdatavalidations)
- [Class DataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)

Comment: Wonderful! Worked beautifully!
Thank you very very much @Tanaike

Comment: @Santoro Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#manual_authorization_scopes_forand for documentation on `@OnlyCurrentDoc`

Comment: @Tanaike You said `And the values of dropdown list are put to the row` and then for the second one `put the values to the column direction` -- is it not the other way around?

Comment: @developer10 Thank you for your comment. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the details of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: It's the following: in the first part you said `And the values of dropdown list are put to the row` but the values were output vertically within a column; for the second part, you said `put the values to the column direction` but this time the values were displayed horizontally in the same row - just the opposite

Comment: @developer10 Thank you for replying. About `It's the following: in the first part you said And the values of dropdown list are put to the row but the values were output vertically within a column; for the second part, you said put the values to the column direction but this time the values were displayed horizontally in the same row - just the opposite`, my 1st and 2nd scripts put the values to the row anc column direction, respectively. I apologize for my poor English skill, again.